# cocoa file association question

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've associated a file type with my application via application properties and by implementind the necessary NSApplication delegate methods. Everything seems to work, but ... this confuses the system. How do i make sure that the files are only associated to the copy of the app that is in Applications folder and not the developement version? Because now my PathFinder shows two identical applications in its open with combobox and i don't want that.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Besides, as a developer, perhaps you can endure that little annoyance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If you have two versions of the same app, the system thinks that both can open the file because, well, they both can. Once an application registers for a particular file type, they system will always report that the app can open that file type. It looks at what the app can do, not where it resides.

Comment: OK then is it at least possible to somehow ensure that after i finish the development for the time being, the correct application is left to open the files? Should i open the one in Applications or open a file with it to make the system think that this is the one it should open from now on?

Comment: When I have multiple versions of one app lying about, I just don't double-click files, I drag files and drop them on the right app.

Comment: @Marius In the Finder or PathFinder you can use the `Open With>other...` to find a path to a particular app bundle at a particular location. However, its not guaranteed to open that particular version of the app. Drag and drop is the only sure method.